# Count rows in Drupal views plugin

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I've written myself a Drupal Views row plugin and I want to count the rows so I can do something with the output every *Nth* row.

I can do this in the plugin's preprocessor function but if it gets used more than once (in panels for example) I can't reset the counter to zero.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default style plugin for views adds a counter to the view object. It is available at

```
$view->row_index
```

If you are overwriting the render method in a custom style plugin remember to duplicate this functionality in your own render function.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the views_customfield module. (http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) This module gives u access to row number in the view and also the option to add PHP code in each row. Pretty handy...

Comment: I don't really want to install a module just to count rows. Thanks anyway.